# Pandas - filter rows using a range of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
DF_TEMP                           Date Home or Away Position  GameWeek  ... Price Goal Threat  Assists Threat  Goal Involvment Threat
Player                                                          ...                                                          
Andrew Robertson    2019-08-09         Home      DEF         1  ...   7.0    0.095392        0.076136                0.171528
Dejan Lovren        2019-08-09         Home      DEF         1  ...   5.5    0.000000        0.000000                0.000000
Joel Matip          2019-08-09         Home      DEF         1  ...   5.5    0.000000        0.000000                0.000000
Joseph Gomez        2019-08-09         Home      DEF         1  ...   5.5    0.000000        0.035294                0.035294
Nathaniel Phillips  2019-08-09         Home      DEF         1  ...   0.0    0.000000        0.000000                0.000000
...                        ...          ...      ...       ...  ...   ...         ...             ...                     ...
Michail Antonio     2020-02-24         Away      MID        27  ...   6.9    0.000000        0.448161                0.448161
Nathan Holland      2020-02-24         Away      MID        27  ...   4.4    0.000000        0.000000                0.000000
Pablo Fornals       2020-02-24         Away      MID        27  ...   6.0    0.427723        0.000000                0.427723
Robert Snodgrass    2020-02-24         Away      MID        27  ...   5.2    0.000000        0.226054                0.226054
Tomas Soucek        2020-02-24         Away      MID        27  ...   5.0    0.000000        0.000000                0.000000
```

If I want to filter it based on 'GameWeek' values, passing a variable, like so:

```
gameweek = 15
```

And simply do:

```
filtered_df = df[df['GameWeek']==gameweek]
```

I will get all rows where 'GameWeek' is 15.

---

QUESTION

But if I pass the same variable `gameweek`, what is the `pandas` way of giving me all rows from 'GameWeek' 1 up to 15?

All my queries should be like this: `[:gameweek]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.le()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) , which basically is less than equals to(`<=`):

```
filtered_df = df[df['GameWeek'].le(gameweek)]
```

**OR**

You can use the actual `<=` operator also:

```
filtered_df = df[df['GameWeek'] <= gameweek]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to get values of `GameWeek` ranging from 1 to 15? A possible way is to query `range()` in the `.isin()` method.

```
filtered_df = df[df['GameWeek'].isin(range(1,16))]
```

Comment: The code snippet is missing `]` from the end, but edits that small aren't allowed.